# Can I loop over properties in ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template where I set up a load balancer and I want to add a number of port openings by adding rules and probes to the LB.

This is the template I have so far:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
        "name": "LB-front",
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "tags": { },
        "properties": {
            "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "LoadBalancerIPConfig",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        "publicIPAddress": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_lbipdev_0_name'))]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "backendAddressPools": [
                {
                    "name": "LoadBalancerBEAddressPool"
                }
            ],
            "loadBalancingRules": [
                {
                    "name": "AppPortLBRule1",
                    "properties": {
                        "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_6')]"
                        },
                        "frontendPort": 80,
                        "backendPort": 80,
                        "enableFloatingIP": false,
                        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "loadDistribution": "Default",
                        "backendAddressPool": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_7')]"
                        },
                        "probe": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_8')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "AppPortLBRule2",
                    "properties": {
                        "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_9')]"
                        },
                        "frontendPort": 81,
                        "backendPort": 81,
                        "enableFloatingIP": false,
                        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "loadDistribution": "Default",
                        "backendAddressPool": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_10')]"
                        },
                        "probe": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_11')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "AppPortLBRule3",
                    "properties": {
                        "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_12')]"
                        },
                        "frontendPort": 82,
                        "backendPort": 82,
                        "enableFloatingIP": false,
                        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "loadDistribution": "Default",
                        "backendAddressPool": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_13')]"
                        },
                        "probe": {
                            "id": "[parameters('loadBalancers_LB_dev_id_14')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "probes": [
                {
                    "name": "AppPortProbe1",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "port": 80,
                        "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                        "numberOfProbes": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "AppPortProbe2",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "port": 81,
                        "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                        "numberOfProbes": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "AppPortProbe3",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "Tcp",
                        "port": 82,
                        "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                        "numberOfProbes": 2
                    }
                }
            ],
            "inboundNatRules": [],
            "outboundNatRules": [],
            "inboundNatPools": []
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_lbipdev_1_name'))]"
        ]
    },
```

(some details omitted)

What I would like to do is to have an array of the port numbers I want to create rules and probes for and loop over those instead of explicitly having to write each rule and probe as a property for the resource.

Basically I would like a parameter or variable in my template like this:

```
"ports": [ 80, 81, 82, ...]
```

and that I could loop over this similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can only apply the copy object to a top-level resource.
>
> **You cannot apply it to a property on a resource type, or to a child resource**.

```
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "{provider-namespace-and-type}",
    "name": "parentResource",
    "copy": {  
      /* yes, copy can be applied here */
    },
    "properties": {
      "exampleProperty": {
        /* no, copy cannot be applied here */
      }
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "{provider-type}",
        "name": "childResource",
        /* copy can be applied if resource is promoted to top level */ 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Source of Quotation: Deploy multiple instances of resources in Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple)

You can loop over properties in ARM Template **ONLY IF** the copy object is applied to a top-level resource, which is in your case the **"Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers"**, but that will also create multiple copy of the said resource.

If this is not what you want to achieve, I would recommend you to keep your existing way until ARM Template support copy object to property on a resource type in the future.

Comment: How can I promote a resource to top level if that resource is technically a child of a "concrete" resource? E.g. WebSite as top level and WebSite/Extension as child level. Could I put the extension resource as a top level declaration and do some form of dependency to the website?

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: @lee-g yes you can declare the child resources on top-level simply be prepending the parent resource's type / name to the child resource's type / name. See here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-resources#child-resources. Once you do this, you can also use property iteration again.

Comment: Not a valid answer anymore

Answer (score 24):

Indeed you can! **Copy does work with properties!**

Create a parameter or variable like this (this example will use parameter array):

```
"lbRules": {
  "type": "array",
  "defaultValue": [
    {
      "name": "httpPort",
      "frontendPort": "80",
      "backendPort": "80",
      "protocol": "tcp"
    },
    {
      "name": "customAppPort",
      "frontendPort": "8080",
      "backendPort": "8888",
      "protocol": "tcp"
    },
    {
      "name": "httpsPort",
      "frontendPort": "443",
      "backendPort": "443",
      "protocol": "tcp"
    }
  ]
}
```

Use this parameter in the Loadbalancer resource using **copy** like this that will create that many probes and rules that you defined in your parameter array:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('lbApiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "name": "[parameters('myLoadBalancer')]",
  "location": "[parameters('computeLocation')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/',concat(parameters('lbIPName'),'-','0'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "LoadBalancerIPConfig",
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAddress": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',concat(parameters('lbIPName'),'-','0'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "backendAddressPools": [
      {
        "name": "LoadBalancerBEAddressPool",
        "properties": {}
      }
    ],

    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "probes",
        "count": "[length(parameters('lbRules'))]",
        "input": {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('probes')].name,'Probe')]",
          "properties": {
            "intervalInSeconds": 5,
            "numberOfProbes": 2,
            "port": "[parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('probes')].backendPort]",
            "protocol": "[parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('probes')].protocol]"

          }
        }
      },

      {
        "name": "loadBalancingRules",
        "count": "[length(parameters('lbRules'))]",
        "input": {
          "name": "[parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].name]",
          "properties": {
            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
              "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('myLoadBalancer')),'/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerIPConfig')]"
            },
            "frontendport": "[parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].frontendport]",
            "backendport": "[parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].backendport]",
            "enableFloatingIP": false,
            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": "5",
            "protocol": "[parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].protocol]",
            "backendAddressPool": {
              "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('myLoadBalancer')),'/backendAddressPools/LoadBalancerBEAddressPool')]"
            },
            "probe": {
              "id": "[concat(variables('lbID0'),'/probes/', parameters('lbRules')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].name,'Probe')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],


    "inboundNatPools": []
  },

  }
}
```

More info can be found here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#property-iteration
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties

Comment: I did this for a client a while back, and I couldn't remember the syntax. This was a great example that outlined the functionality perfectly. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties to be a better resource

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to loop on properties or on child resources as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#property-iteration or in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#create-multiple-instances-of-a-child-resource

You can a child resource extension (e.g. WebSite/Extension) as a top-level resource by following the format for the type:

`{resource-provider-namespace}/{parent-resource-type}/{child-resource-type}.`

For instance

`Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions`

You have also to reference the parent resource in the child resource by a concat. For instance:

`"name": "[concat('mywebsite', '/', 'myextension', copyIndex())]"`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is possible with the **take** function.
You linked the proper documentation site yourself. Go to the link you posted and check out the section *"Create multiple instances when copy won't work"*.

in your case this would look like this:

```
"variables": {
    "probeArray": [                    
           {
             "name": "AppPortProbe1",
             "properties": {
                 "protocol": "Tcp",
                 "port": 80,
                 "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                 "numberOfProbes": 2
             }
           },
           {
             "name": "AppPortProbe2",
             "properties": {
                 "protocol": "Tcp",
                 "port": 81,
                 "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                 "numberOfProbes": 2
             }
           },
           {
             "name": "AppPortProbe3",
             "properties": {
                 "protocol": "Tcp",
                 "port": 82,
                 "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                 "numberOfProbes": 2
             }
           }
    ],
```

You then create an parameter specifying how many probes you want

```
"parameters": {
...
"numProbes": {
  "type": "int",
  "maxValue": 3,
  "metadata": {
    "description": "This parameter allows you to select the number of probes you want"
  }
}
```

Finally you use **take** inside the resource:

```
"resources": [
...
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "properties": {
      ...
      "probes": "[take(variables('probeArray'),parameters('numProbes'))]"
    },
    ...
  }
  ...
}
]
```

If you continue the through the documentation you will see that you can get even more crazy and combine copy and take with linked templates.

Comment: Doesnt this mean that I still have to declare all the probes but jut up in variablea instead? I was hoping for a way to just have to declare them in one chunk and the loop over the only thing that changes, ie the port numbers.

Comment: Yes you have to define the probes when you do it this was. There is no easy way to just iterate through properties with copyIndex().